# Get the ascending order of array element using c language

Tags: c, sorting

I want to replace input array by their order:

`array = { 5, 1, 4 }` ==> `result = { 2, 0 ,1 }`

But I am stuck on how to replace order elements in the same position.

The output is: `0 1 2`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void sort(int tab[], int n) {
    int i, a, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (tab[i] > tab[j]) {
                a =  tab[i];
                tab[i] = tab[j];
                tab[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
}

void getOrder(int tab[]) {
    int i;
    sort(tab, 3);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        tab[i] = i; // replace(tab[i],i)
}

int main() {
    int tab[3] = { 5, 1, 4 }, i, j;
    getOrder(tab);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf(" %d ", tab[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have this array = {50 , 20 , 40 }  and i want to get result array containing the order {3,1,2}  (20 -> 1 , 40 -> 2 , 50 -> 3)

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: array1 = {0,2,5,1,4,3} i should exctact elements {2,5,1} and get their positions {3,1,2} and switch it with another array in the same positions.                              I have tried first sort the elements {2,5,1} == {1,2,5} and according a value to each one and reorder the first array but is not working

Comment: Why is it not working? What's your code? What are the results of that code?

Comment: This smells of "gimme teh codez".

Comment: Provide your code that you have tried  ...

Comment: what i am try to do is exchanging order of a part of array element according to the order of {50,40,10} wich is {3,2,1} ,
till now i have done the exchange function it works perfectly when i provide the order by myself , now i want to reorder dynamicly  the array .


int* exchange(int *A,int *I){

  int i, j, k;
     for(i = 0; i < NbrCities ; i++){
  if(i != I[i]){
      j = i;
      while(i != (k = I[j])){
          swap(A[j], A[k]);
          I[j] = j;
          j = k;
      }
      I[j] = j;
  }
     }
 return A;
}

Comment: Please edit your post with your code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that all values are different, for each value in `tab`, its position in the sorted array is the number of values that are strictly lower in `tab`:

Here is how it works:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void getOrder(const int tab[], int n, int pos[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            count += (tab[j] < tab[i]);
        pos[i] = count;
    }
}

int main() {
    int tab[3] = { 5, 1, 4 };
    int pos[3];
    int n = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(tab[0]);

    getOrder(tab, n, pos);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", pos[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If you want different index values for duplicates, you can use 2 loops with slightly fewer tests:

```
void getOrder(const int tab[], int n, int pos[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int j, count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count += (tab[j] <= tab[i]);
        while (++j < n)
            count += (tab[j] < tab[i]);
        pos[i] = count;
    }
}
```